# Can I debug the export/import of a mixin?

Tags: vue.js

I'm pretty new to vue.js and I'm trying to figure out how to use mixins. 
I wondered if it is possible to create components which are bare of markup/template and contain only logic. As far as I understood, this should be possible and these components are called "mixins":
https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-mixins-in-vue-js-bdcf9e02a7c1

I'm using router functionality.

I'm now just trying out the vary basics of this concept and created the following:

listData1.vue, where the data for a list is created and then exported:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "listData1",
  data() {
    return {
      list1: {
        listData1A : "listData1A",
        listData1A : "listData1B",
        listData1A : "listData1C"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

then listBuilder.vue, which takes the data and then uses it to create a list of items.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="element in list1" v-text="element"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import listData1 from "@/components/complexComponent2/listData1.vue"

export default{
  name: 'listBuilder'
}

</script>
```

And then myComplexView2.vue in my views folder:

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>Second Awesome List!</h1>
  <listBuilder />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import listBuilder from "@/views/myComplexView2.vue"

export default{
  name: 'myComplexView2',
  components: {
    listBuilder
  }
}
</script>
```

Now the result I get is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz4yP.jpg

But it should look like this:
http://localhost:8081/myComplexView

I'm a bit clueless what to do, especially since the vue dev tools in firefox don't show me much: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvtwU.jpg.
Am I accessing the imported incorrectly?
Should I store the data differently, with the `"data : {}"` syntax or should I go for props in the listData component, like this:

```
props:["listData1"]
```

And then add the actual data in the component where the list is constructed with v-for? Though this would kind of undermine my goal to accomplish separating the data from the logic injecting it into the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup `listData1` as mixin in `listBuilder`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="element in list1" v-text="element"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import listData1 from "@/components/complexComponent2/listData1.vue"

export default{
  name: 'listBuilder',
  mixins: [listData1],
}

</script>
```

Otherwise the `ListBuilder` won't have any data.

There's a typo in the mixin data:

```
listData1A : "listData1A",
listData1A : "listData1B",
listData1A : "listData1C"
```

Should be:

```
listData1A : "listData1A",
listData1B : "listData1B",
listData1C : "listData1C"
```

Apart from this, I don't see anything at syntax level in your code that would prevent `mixin` and `v-for` for working.

However, it puzzles me that `myComplexView2` is importing `myComplexView2.vue` as the listBuilder:

```
import listBuilder from "@/views/myComplexView2.vue"
```

I don't know if this is an error you made when pasting to SO. Otherwise, the problem is probably here, since you need to import the `listBuilder` component, not the complex view.

Comment: Hmm, changed it, but on the result nothing changed :(

Comment: Nice, works like a charm! :D Thanks a lot for the help! :))